# Use different (AsyncTask) Loaders in one Activity

Tags: android, android-loader, asynctaskloader

I want to use different AsyncTaskLoaders (different in their return type) in my Activity, what's the best way to implement the callback methods?

This won't work:

> public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
>   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MyPojo>,
>   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MyOtherPojo>

Eclipse says

```
The interface LoaderCallbacks cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments
```

So what do I do? My idea is to make the Activity

> implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>

then check in the callback methods what type of object it is but that doesn't seem too elegant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about creating an inner class for each callback?

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

  private class Callback1 implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MyPojo> {
    ...
  }
  private class Callback2 implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MyOtherPojo> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do u call init loader in this case ?

Comment: @AmeyJahagirdar
With a new Instance of the inner class:
`getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MYPOJO_ID, null, new Callback1());`

Or if several Loaders should use the same callback (the loaders need to be registrered with distinct IDs so onCreateLoader and onLoadFinished can distinguish where the callback was called from) you can have the Activity have a callback member and use this for initLoader(): 
`private final LoaderCallbacks<MyPojo> reusableCallback1 = new LoaderCallbacks<MyPojo> { ... };`